# How to prevent DLLs from being unload before D'tor of global variables in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

My program links **mylib.dll** which links **libfoo.dll**, and **libfoo.dll** loads **libbar.dll** via `LoadLibrary` at runtime. I have a global variable `lib_global` in **mylib.dll**. The structure is like this:

```
  main
    |
mylib.dll { lib_global }
    |
libfoo.dll
    |
    | LoadLibrary
    |
libbar.dll
```

The problem is **libbar.dll** is unloaded before the D'tor of `lib_global` on **Windows**. The exit process is like this:

1. **libbar.dll** is unloaded
2. **mylib.dll** is unloaded

   - D'tor of `lib_global` is called
3. **libfoo.dll** is unloaded

So if **mylib.dll** holds some pointers to functions in **libbar.dll** and the D'tor of `lib_global` invokes the functions to do something via function pointers, the program will crash.

My questions is how to prevent **libbar.dll** from being unload before D'tor of `lib_global`?

Comment: One way is to destruct all your global variables before unloading the `mylib.dll`.  Another way is to not have any global variables.

Comment: Make your global variables in libbar.dl singletons and destruct them before unload.

Comment: Use a `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter to manage ownership of the dll. Have each global variable that needs the dll store such a `shared_ptr` (assuming you can release a DLL after `main()` exits - I simply don't know).